# Android Divide number with decimal fraction

Tags: android, math, division, modulo, calculation

How can i check number is divisible by particular number or not both numbers are decimal. with decimal point value of two digits.
i had tried with below 
`(((dn / size) % 1) == 0)` but in some cases it not provide proper out put. 
how can i resolve it. here i put some example values like 
`double dn = 369.35,369.55.370.55` and size may be `0.05,0.10,0.5` etc...

```
 if(((dn / size) % 1) == 0)    {
       Log.d(TAG,"OK");
    } else {
       Log.d(TAG,"OK");
    }
```

please help me to short out it.

Comment: type cast the values before, then do the math

Comment: can you give me example like ...

Comment: give two proper values and expected output

Comment: above values are proper and they are not static they may change. and output is that i want to check weather is number is divisible by size or not if not then show toast else not.

Comment: you wanted to check if 369.35 is divisible by 0.05 ?

Comment: yes right now it but values are change depends on input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149371/discussion-between-droidev-and-madhav-nimavat).

Answer (score 1):

`(dn / size) % 1 == 0` whilst plausible, will suffer from pitfalls centred around binary floating point arithmetic.

If your numbers always have no more then two decimal places then the easiest thing to do is scale up by multiplying by 100 and rely on the fact that `100 * y` divides `100 * x` if `y` divides `x`. In other words:

```
if (Math.round(100 * dn) % Math.round(100 * size) == 0){
    Log.d(TAG,"Divisible");
} else {
    Log.d(TAG,"Not divisible");
}
```

This obviates any issues with binary floating point arithmetic. I've used `Math.round` rather than a truncation deliberately, again to obviate issues around floating point and am relying on what is in my opinion a quirk of this platform in that `round` returns an integral type.

Further reading: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I cannot round size value

Comment: if i round 0.05 it return 5 which is not ok

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: That doesn't matter since you're also multiplying up `dn`. Try it!

Comment: E.g. exact divisibility of 37042 by 5 is the same as 370.42 by 0.05. Mathematically, that is.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrongly,

try with this code

```
if(dn % size  == 0)    {
  Log.d(TAG,"Divisible");
} else {
   Log.d(TAG,"Not divisible");
}
```

**Update**

Use [BigDecimal](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigDecimal.html) in case you have big decimal numbers

eg :

```
BigDecimal bg1, bg2, bg3;

bg1 = new BigDecimal("513.54");
bg2 = new BigDecimal("5");

// bg2 divided by bg1 gives bg3 as remainder
bg3 = bg1.remainder(bg2);
```

Comment: No it won't in general due to floating point joke digits. You'll get lucky with dyadic rationals.

Comment: 370.42 %0.05 return 0.019999999999995355 and 370.45%0.05 returns 0.049999999999956704

Comment: in that case either you have to use double or BigDecimal

Comment: how can i used it please give me demo